# I have read the Bhagavad Gita as it is. Does Srimad Bhagavatam something more than the gita?

Tags: bhagavata-purana

I really liked reading the Bhagavad Gita.

Is there something more to Srimad Bhagavatam by Srila Prabhupada?

It has 12 Cantos which are really very long and needs patience.

Would the Bhagavatam purana contain something more?

Comment: Bhagwat Gita is teachings of Shree Krishna whereas Bhagwatam Purana have all avatars of bhagwan Vishnu mentioned in details.

Comment: But 12 cantos is way to long to read. Does it just have stories or something more in it?

Comment: I haven't read this one. But I am sure Puranas are more than just stories. Many things can only be understood metaphorically.

Comment: @sly_Chandan Puranas in general contain stories of Gods/Goddesses particularly the one the Purana is dedicated to. Almost all Puranas give origin of universe  as well as description of various Tirtha or Holy Sites.

Comment: @sly_Chandan Bhagvata Purana in particular is dedicated to Sri Krishna. Their are various stories interwined. Including story of Lord Shiva and daksha,stories of various Avatars pf Sri Vishnu as well theological concepts. Finally in 10th canto Sri Krishna avatara comes and in 12 th canto kali yuga is described.

Comment: @sly_Chandan Just use site search with google to find what you want, whenever you want it.

Comment: What about the other authors? Does Srimad Bhagavatam have a consistent stories across all the books even by different authors?